# Convert jquery Alert to tipTip tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tiptip

I have the following code set up in my project as an alert that triggers when the user clicks on a div. The divs are horizontal bar graph elements, each corresponding to a particular measurement. The alert pops up with a bunch of info on those measurements.

```
      $(document).on('click', '.state-entry', function () {

      var startDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
      var duration = seconds2time(Math.round($(this).data('duration') * 86400));

      startDate.setSeconds(86400 * $(this).data('start'));

      var endDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
      endDate.setSeconds(Math.round(86400 * $(this).data('start') + $(this).data('duration') * 86400));

      alert($(this).data('resource') + ' changed state to ' + $(this).data('state') + ' (' + stateNames[$(this).data('state')] + ')\r\nStart Time: ' + startDate.toLocaleTimeString() + '\r\nEnd Time: ' + endDate.toLocaleTimeString() + '\r\nDuration: ' + duration);

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
  });
```

I just want to move all this info into a tooltip rather than an alert. I don't seem to be doing it right though.

I tried the following per tipTip's documentation to just get the tooltip itself to appear and it's not working.:

```
    $(function(){
$(".state-entry").tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10});
});
```

How would I move in this info in my jQuery to this tooltip type, not sure what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, and if any more code is needed/I need to set up a jsfiddle, I can. But hoping this is enough of the code for you to get an idea of what I'm working with. Thanks again.

Comment: But..looking at more code is sometimes helpful....BTW.. how do you include your tipTip script...You should do it after including jquery js

Comment: I'll throw something together in jsfiddle so all the code can be seen. Give me a moment. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dvzCN/. Are you creating the `.state-entry` dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming that you are adding the `state-entry` divs dynamically?

if so when you create one you have to `tiptip`it when it is created.

[here is a fiddle that shows dynamic elements not working unless you `tiptip` them.](http://jsfiddle.net/dvzCN/3/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this input. Yeah, each of these `.state-entry` are being dynamically created. I will try doing the same with the tiptip when they are created and comment/upvote later. Thanks for all the input guys.

(And yeah, wasn't able to really use the jsfiddle, there's a lot of code here in css/html/js, but this may be it)